# Is there a test or trial to become a padawan?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, jedi-training

We know that Jedi are recruited at a very young age. Anakin Skywalker himself was deemed "too old" to begin training at 9 years old. We also know that younglings are assigned in groups to a Jedi Master to begin their training, as we saw in Attack of the Clones and the Clone Wars TV series (I see it as an elementary school or something. A group of students assigned to one classroom and one teacher).

Obi-Wan Kenobi began training with Qui-Gon Jinn at 12 years old. I assume that before that he was considered a youngling.

We also know that in order to become a Jedi Knight, a padawan must take "The Trials".

So my question is: Is there a similar test or "trial" for a youngling to become a padawan, or apprentice? Do they just reach certain age and are assigned a Jedi Master to train one-on-one?

Comment: Non-canon, but it would be the [Jedi Initiate Trials](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jedi_Initiate_Trials).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although he was initially rejected by the council, we DO see Anakin being tested by the Jedi Council in [**Star Wars Episode I: The Phantom Menace**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_I:_The_Phantom_Menace). This test seems to consist of not only interview questions and a psychological evaluation, but also an [ESP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extrasensory_perception) test where he must correctly guess what is depicted on Master Windu's datapad:

[image]

Since the Council's stated reason for rejecting Anakin was his age, it's probably safe to assume that he passed the tests we see on-screen. Otherwise, it would have been easier for the Council to reject him based on that failure.

However, given that most Padawans are selected while infants, it would stand to reason that a less interactive test - such as [Midi-chlorian count](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Midi-chlorian) - is used for their initial selection and inclusion into the Order as an [**Initiate**](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jedi_Initiate).

Once a child is old enough - generally as they enter their teen years - they are allowed to take the [Initiate Trials](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jedi_Initiate_Trials) for consideration as a [**Padawan Learner**](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Padawan). The Initiate Trials vary from era to era, but generally test a student's knowledge of the [Jedi Code](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jedi_Code), life as a Jedi, and possibly construction of their first [lightsaber](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lightsaber). If they pass the trials, they are then elevated to Padawan rank and assigned to a [Jedi Master](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jedi_Master) for one-on-one instruction.

Comment: This seems to be more of a test of his force abilities in general

Comment: @Richard you're probably right, but so far it's the only on-screen example we have of someone being tested for entry.

Comment: @SJuan76 : lol, no when you watch the scene, Anakin is naming what appears on the pad. It's an update to the test where you guess what shape appears on a card facing away from you. Standard ESP test as developed by Joseph Rhine.

Answer (score 3):

This is discussed at some considerable length in the [Jedi Path Manual](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Star-Wars-Manual-Students-Force/dp/0857685872). In short, Padawans can attempt the attract the attention of a Jedi Master by participating in a lightsaber competition. You can also ask the Temple's teachers to recommend you to a Master if you have a special talent (such as an affinity with animals or tech).

[image]

Additionally, in the Clone Wars series Ahsoka was assigned to Anakin by Yoda and the Jedi Council. There's also a mention in KOTOR of a [Jedi initiation trial](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jedi_Initiate_Trials) involving a test of your knowledge of the Force and ability to construct a working lightsaber.

Comment: I remember an arc in the Clone Wars TV series, not sure if season 4 or 5, where younglings were taken to a cave to look for their lightsaber crystal (I'm terrible at remembering names, I'm sorry if it sounds confusing). After that, they were still younglings, weren't they?

Comment: @tilley31 - I believe so. Let me check